# RPM bin Dependency on shared library inside lib

Tags: linux, shared-libraries, rpm

I am having following structure

```
bin/
   bin 1 
   bin 2 

lib / 
     lib1 
     lib2
```

Where lib1 and lib2 are dynamic library. and bin1 and bin2 are depending on lib1 and lib2.

When I am trying to install rpm I am getting error

```
app-0.0.1-1.x86_64 requires lib1.so()(64bit)
```

which I am already giving inside lib1 folder. What flags should I set so it can look for the library inside lib folder ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the possible reasons could be that the library is not installed using `rpm`. You may check it using the following options:

```
rpm -q --whatprovides /fullpath/lib/lib1.so
```

Not sure about (64bit)-part of the warning, perhaps the installed one is 32-bit.

If you're absolutely sure that the correct library is installed you may try `--nodeps` option of `rpm`.

Comment: library is not installed. I am giving it in inside bin.

Comment: rpm is checking its database, not the filesystem - you're either need to force it to install the package with nodeps, or create meta rpm package that PROVIDES /fullpath/lib/lib1.so